# Error converting to float ignoring WHERE filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a `varchar` column, PaymentRef, containing a variety of text and numeric data. Furthermore, there's a column, CurrencyAmount of datatype `float`:

```
PaymentRef               CurrencyAmount
----------               --------------
EUR 100,00               100
EUR 50,00                50
USD 25,00                25.2
Auth#: 98103             NULL
Auth#: 98104             NULL
Transferred from 2356    NULL
Transferred to 1356      NULL
```

Now whenever a record contains a PaymentRef on the form "EUR ##,##", "USD ##,##", etc. I need to compare the numeric value after the currency code, to the value of the CurrencyAmount column.

The following query works just fine:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.') AS FLOAT) AS PaymentRefNumeric,
    CurrencyAmount
FROM MyTable
WHERE LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
```

However, if I try to compare the casted value to the CurrencyAmount column, as in:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.') AS FLOAT) AS PaymentRefNumeric,
        CurrencyAmount
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE PaymentRefNumeric <> CurrencyAmount
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I know that I can easily put the result of the first query into a temporary table, and then perform my comparison, but I'm wondering what the cause of this error is. I believe it has something to do with the query optimizer attempting to CAST the PaymentRef values to FLOAT, before applying the first WHERE filter. Is there a way to ensure the filter is applied before the values are cast? (That's why I tried using CTE's, but even without CTE's I still get the same error).

Comment: i encountered the same thing when i wanted to convert varchar to date eliminating invalid dates. i ended up putting the calculated column into a case statement duplicating the where. +1 because i'd like a proper answer myself.
afaik the problem comes up when using where on a function. sql server has to see the data first before applying the where, thus already executing the cast

Comment: If you're dealing with currency, you should almost certainly be using something other than `float`, such as either the `decimal` type or `int` (if the latter, it would be storing e.g. 100ths of a cent)

Comment: Thanks Damien, I know what the difference between fixed and floating point data types is, but that is completely unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: The reason the conversion doesn't Err in some cases is because the WHERE statement is run before the SELECT statement. If the row with the conversion error filters out the conversion error will not occur.   See my answer where I use ISNUMERIC to make sure the select always returns Numeric comparable values.

Comment: @Dan Are you using SQL2012? If so TRY_CAST can be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a workaround as described in my comment

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT case when LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
                then CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.') AS FLOAT) 
                else null
                end AS PaymentRefNumeric,
        CurrencyAmount
    FROM #t WHERE LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE PaymentRefNumeric <> CurrencyAmount
```

Comment: Thanks - this is definitely a usable solution, and I will probably do something like this in my case. I'll leave the question open for now, as I still would like an explanation to the behavior of the query optimizer and what causes the error.

Comment: agreed, i'd like that as well. also a proper solution. this just does not feel quite right.

Comment: @Dan - the error is caused by an overeager optimizer, and the solutions are to use `CASE` and hope the optimizer doesn't get any more eager or to actually split the query into two separate queries and use some form of temp table between them to stage the results. CTEs, subqueries, etc, are all absorbed into a single query to be optimized. If you think that this is an insane situation to be in, please go and add your vote to [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Answer (score 1):

can't you change the where condition of the CTE to

```
WHERE CurrencyAmount IS NOT NULL
```

? your sample data looks like that would be ok ... the query works with the changed condition ...

you could also change the other where condition to

```
WHERE currencyamount is not null and PaymentRefNumeric <> CurrencyAmount
```

Comment: While this works in my particular case, I will not flag it as an answer, since the CurrencyAmount column could theoretically contain non-null values even when the PaymentRef column is not on the form "CUR ##,##"

Answer (score 0):

Use IsNull Function:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.') AS FLOAT) AS PaymentRefNumeric,
        CurrencyAmount
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE PaymentRefNumeric <> IsNull(CurrencyAmount, -1) -- Check if is null so replce it
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem - still the same error. I would prefer to use PrfctByDsgn's suggestion instead, if I wanted to filter by non-null CurrencyAmount records.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNUMERIC to check if the conversion succeeded otherwise return NULL.
This will cover all bases.

For SQL2012 users the TRYCAST Function can be use. If the cast fails NULL is returned.
Just replace the CASE expression with:

`SQL2012 TRY_CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.'))`

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN 
         ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.'))=1
       THEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.') AS FLOAT) 
       ELSE NULL
       END PaymentRefNumeric
    ,CurrencyAmount
FROM MyTable
WHERE LEFT(PaymentRef, 3) IN ('EUR', 'USD', 'SEK')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE PaymentRefNumeric <> CurrencyAmount
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't help. `select ISNUMERIC('£')` returns 1. `select CAST('£' as float)` produces an error.

Comment: @Dan In SQL2012 TRY_CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PaymentRef, 5, 100), ',', '.'))   can be used